Ansible get_url returning 400
When downloading a file with Ansible get_url from JFrog Artifactory it always returns a 400. While trying this with curl works perfectly.
Ansible task with get_url that doesn't work:
- name: Download file
  ansible.builtin.get_url:
    url: 'https://xxx.jfrog.io/artifactory/xxx-yyy-zzz/file-adsds-1234.somefile_xxx.tgz'
    headers:
      Authorization: 'Bearer {{ artifactory_token }}'
    dest: '/opt/file.tgz'
    mode: '0600'

Task that works with curl:
- name : Download file
  shell: "curl -L -S -H 'Authorization: Bearer {{ artifactory_token }}' 'https://xxx.jfrog.io/artifactory/xxx-yyy-zzz/file-adsds-1234.somefile_xxx.tgz' --output '/opt/file.tgz'"
  args:
    creates: "/opt/file.tgz"

EDIT:
After testing out more get_url does seem to work when I don't use the Authorization header, but the basic auth authentication using username:token. This does not clear up to me why this would be the case, but I hope someone has ideas based on the internal workings of Ansible get_url.

Neither is "doesn't work" a problem descripton, nor it is reproducible, nor is a specific programming question here. You may have a look at How do I ask a good question?, How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example, Why is "Can someone help me?" not a useful question?.

I would think from context you would understand that "doesn't work" means I get a HTTP 400 Bad Request. I believe that Ansible is part of the "specific programming" questions right? As this is something specific most likely between Ansible get_url and JFrog Artifactory I would think this is a logical location. I get your point on reproducibility, you would need to setup everything exactly as we have in our company for which I don't know exactly what is there and what is not there as I am not from the platform team. But asking a question to get an idea from someone who knows the details

I've an setup where my example is just working without any issue and I am not able produce a problem or issue.

I was afraid of something like that @U880D , so that would mean it is something very specific to my setup and I'll need to go and debug at all levels with my platform team.... (or just use the basic auth setup, which is most likely what I will do). Thanks for looking into it though!

You will probably need to get in touch with the platform team, review and analyze debug logs from the repository service, check on docs like https://jfrog.com/help/r/artifactory-how-to-debug-artifactory-issues-based-on-http-status-codes/400-bad-request and so on. Based on the currently given information and my test result the issue seems not related to Ansible.

Just some notes before ... Neither is "doesn't work" a problem descripton, nor it is reproducible, nor is a specific programming question here. You may have a look at How do I ask a good question?, How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example, Why is "Can someone help me?" not a useful question?.

After generating a valid Access Token according the documentation, a minimal example playbook
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    URL: repository.example.com
    FILE: example.png
    TOKEN: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123

  tasks:

  - name: Download from Artifactory
    get_url:
      url: "https://{{ URL }}/artifactory/SHARE/{{ FILE }}"
      headers:
        Authorization: 'Bearer {{ TOKEN }}'
      dest: "/tmp"
      mode: 0600

called in verbose mode
ansible-playbook bearer.yml -vvvv

will result into an output of
TASK [Download from Artifactory] **************************************************************
task path: /home/ansible-user/test/bearer.yml:14
changed: [localhost] => changed=true
  checksum_dest: null
  checksum_src: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcd
  dest: /tmp/example.png
  elapsed: 0
  gid: 1234567890
  group: users
  invocation:
    module_args:
      attributes: null
      backup: false
      checksum: ''
      ciphers: null
      client_cert: null
      client_key: null
      decompress: true
      dest: /tmp
      force: false
      force_basic_auth: false
      group: null
      headers:
        Authorization: Bearer abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123
      http_agent: ansible-httpget
      mode: 384
      owner: null
      selevel: null
      serole: null
      setype: null
      seuser: null
      timeout: 10
      tmp_dest: null
      unredirected_headers: []
      unsafe_writes: false
      url: https://repository.example.com/artifactory/SHARE/example.png
      url_password: null
      url_username: null
      use_gssapi: false
      use_netrc: true
      use_proxy: true
      validate_certs: true
  md5sum: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcd
  mode: '0600'
  msg: OK (4936 bytes)
  owner: ansible-user
  secontext: system_u:object_r:tmp_t:s0
  size: 4936
  src: /home/ansible-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1234567890.1234567-1234567-123456789012345/tmpabcd1234
  state: file
  status_code: 200
  uid: 1234567890
  url: https://repository.example.com/artifactory/SHARE/example.png

and leave the file downloaded at
ll /tmp/example.png
-rw-------. 1 ansible-user users 4936 Dec 20 08:00 /tmp/example.png

Same as a call from CLI would do
curl --silent --location -H 'Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}' -O 'https://repository.example.com/artifactory/SHARE/example.png'


Yeah I get that this is an example, point here is if anyone would know of a reason why I would receive back a 400 bad request from jfrog with get_url and not with curl. The whole point is that it doesn't make sense as it should do "exactly" the same

@Wealot, as you can see from my test, it is working the same and do exactly the same. I am not able reproduce any issue or different behavior.
